# Make Google Search Console ignore missing review and rating

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console complains that the "review" and "aggregateRating" are missing (optional) on the product scheme

A lot of posts say "Just ignore it, it's optional"

But we are never ever going to get reviews. As in never.

Is there really no way of turning these warnings so I don't see the 746 products with these useless warnings, which hide the few products which DO have errors in the descriptions?

I'm tempted to add a 5-star rating and a revivw saying "we like this product" on all products to get rid of the warnings, but I'm not sure it's a good idea ;-)

Comment: Is this part of [product](https://schema.org/Product) schema?

Comment: Yes. Modified question.

Comment: Does Google give a rich snippet for products without reviews and aggregate ratings?    There isn't any ranking benefit to using schema, so if Google isn't displaying your product pages specially in the search results, you could just remove the schema markup from the products altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses product/review schema to display review stars, price, and stock status. If you provide none of those details you get an error, if you have no reviews you get a warning. These errors and warnings are purely to do with your ability to get rich snippets in Google.

I would not remove schema just because of a warning or error related to rich snippets. That information may be of value in other ways, like for the merchant centre feed or for less visible use by Google.

Why not submit feedback in GSC with your request. If enough people send feedback that may improve it.